# Best approach to export data from Excel file to SQL Server table using C# and ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, excel

I made a little web app to able users to upload a `.xlsx` file to the server's database table, but I hit a wall with the OLEDB connection string:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'El proveedor 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' no está registrado en el equipo local.'

Since the app is going to be uploaded into the company's server installing x32 drivers are a no go and changing the project to run as x32 release also didn't help either. I'm looking for a better approach to make this possible and keeping the .xlsx file as the users input.

```
protected void btnImportar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        //SUBE Y GUARDA ARCHIVO
        string rutaArchivo = Server.MapPath(subeArchivo.FileName);

        string excelPath = Server.MapPath("~/cargas/") + Path.GetFileName(subeArchivo.PostedFile.FileName)/* + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")*/;
        lblRutaArchivo.Text = rutaArchivo;

        subeArchivo.SaveAs(excelPath);

        string conStringExcel = string.Empty;
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(subeArchivo.PostedFile.FileName);

        switch (extension)
        {
            case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                conStringExcel = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03conStringExcel"].ConnectionString;
                break;

            case ".xlsx": //Excel 07 or higher
                conStringExcel = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07+conStringExcel"].ConnectionString;
                break;
        }

        conStringExcel = string.Format(conStringExcel, excelPath);

        using (OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conStringExcel))
        {
            connExcel.Open(); // ERROR SHOWS UP HERE
            string hojaExcel = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["CAR_DCT"].ToString();
            DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();

            //TODAS LAS COLUMNAS COMO STRING
            dtExcelData.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[7] {
               new DataColumn("ID_USU_CAR", typeof(string)),
               new DataColumn("RUT_DCT", typeof(string)),
               new DataColumn("TIP_CON", typeof(string)),
               new DataColumn("ID_CON", typeof(string)),
               new DataColumn("INI_BEN", typeof(string)),
               new DataColumn("FIN_BEN", typeof(string)),
               new DataColumn("MON_CLP", typeof(string))
            });

            using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + hojaExcel + "]", connExcel))
            {
                oda.Fill(dtExcelData);
            }

            connExcel.Close();

            using (connSQL)
            {
                using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connSQL))
                {
                    //Set the database table name
                    sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.TH_AD.CAR_DCT_BEN_TMP";

                    //MAPEO COLUMNAS
                    //ID_USU_CARGA RUT_DV  TIP_CON ID_CON  INI_BEN FIN_BEN MON_CLP

                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("ID_USU_CAR", "ID_USU_CAR");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("RUT_DCT", "RUT_DCT");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("TIP_CON", "TIP_CON");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("ID_CON", "ID_CON");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("INI_BEN", "INI_BEN");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("FIN_BEN", "FIN_BEN");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("MON_CLP", "MON_CLP");

                    connSQL.Open();
                    sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData);
                    connSQL.Close();
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: If you are using SQL connection you could use SqlConnection instead. It's more efficient than OleDb but limits you to SQL. Also, you should probably think about using parameters for hojaExcel to avoid sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

try to check Spire.XLS, it has function to get DataTable and you can then load to your bulk function.